# why codeigniter captcha doesn't change in internet explorer?

Tags: php, codeigniter, internet-explorer, captcha

i create a login page with codeigniter 3.
my captcha code works perfect in firefox and other modern browsers. but in internet explorer if you refresh the page it DOESN'T CHANGE. whats wrong with my codes?

Here is the link to the page: http://www.artavil.ir/myadmin/

My captcha code:

```
function create(){

    $rand = rand(1000,9999);


    $config_captcha = array(
        'word' => $rand,
        'img_path'=> './captcha_pic/',
        'img_url'=> 'http://artavil.ir/myadmin/captcha_pic/',
        'img_width' =>'150',
        'img_height' =>'30',
        'expiration' => 7200
    );
    $captcha = create_captcha($config_captcha);

    echo $captcha['image'];

}
```

Comment: Please construct a complete example of the code that causes the problem including the markup for the view.  Linking to a demo is fine, but it's not good enough as your OP must also contain the relevant code.  Please read and follow:  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are it's getting cached. Try this in your JS to prevent caching:

```
$("#captcha").load("http://www.artavil.ir/myadmin/captcha/create?" + Date.now());
```

Comment: How can it possibly get cached when the file name of the JPG is different for each new captcha image?

Comment: @Sparky View the source. `http://www.artavil.ir/myadmin/captcha/create` is the file being loaded via AJAX. That file will potentially be cached. That it prints a new filename each time doesn't prevent it from being cached.

Comment: Ok then, you have a good point.  However, the ajax or a description of the ajax function, is missing from the OP.  As a matter of principle, I will not dig through code only accessible via external links.